# laravel 8 relationship with nested query not working

Tags: php, eloquent

Why when using an internal query for relationships it doesn't work like this.

```
 Customer::where('contract_id',$request->contract_id)->with(
      [
          'claims'=> function ($q){
                $q->select('id');
            }
      ])->get();
```

, when you cancel the function, it works internally

```
 Customer::where('contract_id',$request->contract_id)->with( ['claims'])->get();
```